# gitkraken abruply closes while opening a repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitkraken

I just installed gitkraken(8.2.1) in grauda arch linux and as soon as i click open a repo button it abruptly closes without any warning or error.

I have found some solutions like this:

1. tried deleting .gitkraken dir
2. reinstalling gitkraken
3. didn't run vscode concurrently with gitkraken

But nothing seems to work. If anyone can solve this issue i highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the **index** file in your `Project/.git`, it's a hidden folder. If that doesn't work either, try to delete and re-clone the repo that GitKraken was trying to open.

Comment: But the problem is not with the git repo. Even after opening the repo and giving the repo path it just closes.

Comment: Did you try to open another git repo ? I don't the think the issue is GitKraken from the moment you already reinstalled it, did you also check if there are some compatibility issues with the version that you are using ? Is the pathname of your repository too long ? There could also be an issue with the directory path itself. Try cloning this repository to a different local directory.

Comment: You could also try to launch the application from the terminal to verify that there are no missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and I found the solution, maybe it could be of interest for you.

I forgot I had clicked on `Use local SSH agent` here:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw6Oa.png)

Now I unclicked it and it came back working. If you cannot unclick it because Gitkraken closes continuosly, delte the .gitkraken dir and, before uploading any repo, unflag that setting.

That's actually a major issue for Gitkraken.

Hope it can be useful.

PS: I apologize for having answered previously following up with my same problem, I thought it was better to avoid opening another thread. I won't do it anymore.